# Alternative to unistd.h getopt using c++ stl

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, argv

I'm writing a C++ command line application for users that we will be used on various platforms. For this reason, I am writing using only stl. I'm wondering if stl has a nice way to parse input arguments similar to the getopt function used in `unistd.h/getopt.h` (as these are not platform independent to my knowledge). I've already thought of doing something like `while/for loop` and `switch` statements, but wondering if there something a bit more elegant. C++11 is ok, boost is not.

Comment: Just to understand, why boost is not allowed ?

Comment: Basically, I was told that this program can not have any "dependencies" and to only use stl. I realize this is a bit awkward given that C++11 is allowed - I guess we're just assuming they have up to date compilers? Either way it comes down to it not being my decision, and my boss thinking that boost may be a hassle for some users who don't want to "download extra things."

Comment: I like your boss' view on things. Lean and mean is the way to go. But... the problem with portable command line handling is, that while there are standards (POSIX, see e.g. here http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/basedefs/V1_chap12.html ), the command line syntax differs between *nix and windows for example. So, a "portable" solution would have to accept  not one command line syntax but one syntax per OS family.

Comment: There isn't. You'll have to write your own, which will waste time that could be used to write actually useful code in your program. A classical example of Not Invented Here syndrome. There's a reason everyone uses getopt/boost.program_options for anything more than `--help`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to write your own or use boost. As of C++11, there is no standard "getopt" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that there isn't a way in standard C++ but [`getopt`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/getopt.html) is a POSIX standard, which covers a lot of platforms (Linux, *NIX, *BSD, MacOS, iOS, Android, Cygwin).

On native Win32 simply embed something like [wingetopt](https://github.com/alex85k/wingetopt) into your project (BSD-licensed). Also FreeBSD [getopt.c](https://github.com/lattera/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/getopt.c) can be easily ported (though it doesn't support long option format).

Comment: getopt is POSIX but at the same time it is GPL licensed, which requires your code to be free as well, which is not a nice feature

Comment: GNU getopt is GPL-licensed, if you need to bundle it, it would be prudent to pick a BSD-licensed one instead (I provided a couple of links in my answer). On GNU/Linux, getopt is part of GLIBC, which is [LGPL](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=COPYING.LIB), so there is no problem.